# Cocos2D: How do you make a CCMenu scrollable so offscreen menu items can be viewed?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone, menuitem

I'm new to Cocos, but one of the first things I needed to do is make a CCMenu scrollable, and there doesn't appear to be a way to do this out of the box. I read there are touch interaction problems with putting CCmenu inside a UIScrollView.

What my code does is add all the labels to the menu and call:

```
CCMenu* menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, nil];
```

The menu is positioned center, and the top and bottom items display offscreen. I might be able to hack it to view them all by using vertical padding or something, the API seems to support that, but really what I need is a dynamic menu that allows scrolling if there are too many items to view. Is there an easy way to do this, besides extending CCMenu to scroll and managing touches to allow that?

Comment: i think the [looping menu](http://pocketworx.com/?p=167) would solve your problem....

Answer (score 0):

Just so that the question doesn't continue to show up as unanswered.

As Marine correctly says you could use the [looping menu](http://pocketworx.com/?p=167)

Cocos2d also includes a CCScrollLayer which can be found on the [Cocos2d Iphone Extensions](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions) GitHub page along with some example implementation.